# Why is the modulating shape appear in both sides of the carrier signal in AM?

Tags: radio-frequency

It's about Amplitude Modulation. Can anyone tell me why is this signal wave or modulating waveform shape appears in both sides of the carrier sine wave? Why not in one side only?

$$x_c(t) = A_c[1 + \mu x_m(t)]\cos(\omega_ct)$$

I copied this image from Wikipedia
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: AC coupling. Even if you tried to do modulation on one side only, AC coupling would make it appear symmetrically about zero. It is neither practical, nor necessary, to do single sided modulation.

And the expression you have shows that there is a number that multiplies the cosine function. That means the cosine will be multiplied both while it is going positive and while it is going negative. So the math and the image agree with each other. Note that the '$\mu x(t)$' factor has to be greater than -1 always - otherwise you get weird effects that you will experience as distortion (if the multiplier goes negative, the amplitude starts to increase again...)

Comment: Is there any mathematical explanation you can give? That would be a great help :)

Comment: I made some edits as you wrote your comment. Is your doubt resolved yet?

Comment: Yea now it's kinda clear :) That happens because it is a cosine right? So it alternates.

Comment: Exactly. The cosine function itself goes positive and negative. If you multiply it by 2, it gets bigger on both sides. If you multiply it by 0.5, it gets smaller on both sides... So whether you look at the positive envelope or the negative one, you will see the modulating function. But on the negative side it will be flipped.

Comment: @Floris, you wrote "It is neither practical, nor necessary, to do single sided modulation" but almost all modern modulation schemes are single sideband by being "IQ". Even in the good (bad?) old days of analog radio SSB was gaining over DSB and certainly SSB was the preferred way in anything but broadcast.

Comment: Now I get the mystery behind that :)

Comment: @hyportnex It is not SSB I think. It is limiting the shape of the modulated signal to a one side right? That is not possible right?

Comment: @hyportnex - "single side band" is not the same thing as "asymmetrical in the AC sense" which is how I was using it. OP was asking about the symmetry of the AM modulated curve.

Comment: @Blogger There are several ways of generating SSB, one is by filtering out one of the sidebands, another is using balanced mixer pairs (Weaver and some such). Filtering is usually easier to understand but more difficult in practice. The NTSC  US TV broadcast waveform is almost  single sideband, it filters almost all one side but leaves enough so a simple envelope detector can be used as a cheap receiver. A true SSB signal cannot be detected with a simple envelope detector, it needs phase synchronous detection.

Comment: I only knew about the filtering method. Thanks for pointing out what's beyond :)